# Why is a PHP max_input_vars warning not being reported by my error handler?

Tags: php, error-handling

I have a custom error handler which reports errors in a nice readable fashion, so I don't need to go spelunking in log files.

```
error_reporting(-1);
set_error_handler(array('Oops', 'onError'));
set_exception_handler(array('Oops', 'onException'));
```

This works for warnings.

```
// undefined constant, generates a warning
$t = I_AM_NOT_DEFINED;
```

This reports, as it should,

```
Use of undefined constant I_AM_NOT_DEFINED - assumed 'I_AM_NOT_DEFINED' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)
```

However, a large POST request lands a warning in the Apache log file, but nothing is reported to the error handler:

```
[Thu Apr 01 11:04:50.331404 2021] [php7:warn] [pid 26496] [client 127.0.0.1:38032] PHP Warning:  Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini. in Unknown on line 0, referer: http://develop.local/large_post_test
```

Is this warning somehow generated in a special place so it bypasses the normal error handling code? The fact that the warning is generated in Unknown on line 0 suggests that something odd is happening.

Comment: Parsing of the request body, to populate $_POST, happens before your own code even runs.

Comment: That makes sense, I suppose. No real way to catch this error, then. I wasn't aware of it until users reported errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As CBroe points out in a comment, the `$_POST` body is populated before any user-written code runs, and therefore before the custom error handler (or any `display_errors()` calls) are run. Therefore, any errors in populating `$_POST` will be reported the default way as defined in `php.ini` (or as over-written by any `php_value` statements in `.htaccess`).

Since `.htaccess` files are parsed before PHP is executed, you can override values there, such as

```
php_value max_input_vars 10000
```

which will allow larger inputs. You could also override which errors PHP displays, and where it logs them, though it may be neater to do this in `php.ini` files.

Precisely because `$_POST` is populated before the code runs, a command like `ini_set('max_input_vars', 10000)` will not work.